# Alignment issues with TableLayout when adding Buttons

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I created a `TableLayout` for my application. Everything is working fine, but once I add the button image at the bottom of the page the alignment breaks. Here is an image before entering the button image code:

[image]

After entering the code for the button images:

[image]

My xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:background="@drawable/authenticinfo">  
    <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="18dp"              
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
      <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView               
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="38dp"              
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
        <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView2"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="38dp"               
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>      
            <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imview"            
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"          
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            /> 
    </TableRow>  
     <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView              
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="20dp"               
            android:gravity="center"  
            ></TextView>  
    </TableRow>     
             <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/ProductID1"  
            android:text="Product ID"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/ProductID2"  
            android:text=":"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/ProductID3"  
            android:text="92173ad0"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
    </TableRow>     
             <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/ProductID4"  
            android:text="产品编号 "  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/ProductID5"  
            android:text=":"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/ProductID6"  
            android:text="92173ad0"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
    </TableRow>     
              <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView               
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="8dp"               
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
    </TableRow> 
<TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Manf1"  
            android:text="生产日期  "  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Manf2"  
            android:text=":"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Manf3"  
            android:text="01 Jan 2012"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
    </TableRow> 
<TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow10"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Exp1"  
            android:text="有效日期  "  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Exp2"  
            android:text=":"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Exp3"  
            android:text="01 Jan 2015"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow11"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView               
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="8dp"               
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  
    <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow12"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Mas1"  
            android:text="马来西亚出口许可证   "  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Mas2"  
            android:text=":"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/Mas3"  
            android:text=""  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
     <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow13"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/China1"  
            android:text="中国的进口许可证   "  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/China2"  
            android:text=":"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/China3"  
            android:text=""  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>
    </TableRow>    
      <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow14"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView               
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:typeface="serif"  
            android:textSize="28dp"               
            android:gravity="center"  
            android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
    </TableRow>  


<TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow15"  
        >  
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imbutt"            
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"          
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="@+drawable/buttonmainmenuoff"
            /> 
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imbutt"            
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"          
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="@+drawable/buttonmainmenuoff"
            /> 
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imbutt"            
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"          
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="@+drawable/buttonmainmenuoff"
            /> 
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: And where exactly are those `Main Menu` buttons at the end in your xml layout?

Comment: Please check my code now...added the main menu button code....

Comment: Why put them in the table, put them outside of it underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout breaks because the `ImageViews` that you add at the end stretch the columns where they are placed(for example the second `ImageView` that you add will stretch the `TextView` that holds the `:`). You don't say how you want them placed but one simple thing that you could do is to wrap them in another layout, like `LinearLayout` like this:

```
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow15" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imbutt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imbutt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imbutt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Of course you could spread them if you want, with the `layout_weight` attribute.

As a side note, do you really have 6 columns in your layout(you set the `layout_span` to `6`)? Also , do you use those empty singular `TextViews` or you just use them as dividers(if this is what you want, then you could consider a simple `View` element outside the `TableRows` with the desired height)?